# How to organizate custom SQl queres collection

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlite, windows-phone-7

I'm developing an app for Windows Phone with SQlite and have a lot of custom  SQL queries. Like

```
string query = "SELECT distinct(destinations.name) as Destinations 
                FROM destinations, flights 
                WHERE destinations.d_ID = flights.d_ID 
                AND flights.Date = #" + date.ToShortDateString() + "#";
```

then run:

```
 var result = (Application.Current as App).db.Query(query);
```

For working with SQlite i'm using http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx#s2-introduction-to-sqlite-client-for-windows-phone
and theirs DBHelper

I want all Queries will be in one place, so I can quickly change them.

Wanted to ask how to do it correctly?

- create one static class
- create Enum or Dictionary with queries collection
- create some XML or similar file with collection -

Thanks for advise

Comment: How do you work with query results? Maybe it makes sense to work with the object repositories and store queries inside their implementations?

Comment: Note: you *really* want to parameterize that query.  In this case, it doesn't look like you'll do much harm, but for text-based inputs, you don't want to succumb to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @casperOne: Pfft, [what can go wrong with that?](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Patrick Would have been better if [Little Bobby Tables](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148949/littlebobbytables) actually made the comment but good one none-the-less. =)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think any of the approaches are valid, for the following reasons:

**Create one static class**

This is a [God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) and is considered an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), best to stay away from it.  It's just going to be a nightmare to maintain.

**create Enum or Dictionary with queries collection**

Instead of having a God object now, you have a God collection, and are really just implementing the same anti-pattern in a different way.

Additionally, you'll have string keys (or enum keys) and there's not a strong link between the two (what if the dictionary doesn't populate for some reason?).

**create some XML or similar file with collection**

It could be argued that you're doing the same thing you would be doing with a dictionary; you'd have to key the query *somehow* and then look it up.  It's a very brittle approach.

**Possible solution**

I recommend that you first abstract out your data layer into logical units.  Create a class for data operations which are related.

For example, if you have a few queries and operations that are related to destinations, create an interface that exposes those operations:

```
public interface IDestinationDataOperations
{
    // Get destinations by date.
    IEnumerable<string> GetDestinationsByDate(DateTime asOf);
}
```

Then, create a class that implements this which is specific to SQL Lite.  Where you want to make the calls, the variable is of the *interface* type.

The benefits of this are:

- If you change the implementation from SQL Lite to some other underlying data store (web service call, JSON REST call, whatever) you only have to change where you populate the interface variable (this is where [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) begins to be of use), as all of your calls are against the *abstraction*
- The interface is more easily testable:

  - You can test the direct implementation against any test data you want
  - For items that rely on the interface, you can mock the interface any way you like and not have an *actual* database underneath for testing.

Then, for other data operations, you can wash, rinse, and repeat.

For bonus points, you can separate out the interface into a [unit-of-work](http://www.google.com/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html&q=unit%20of%20work&ei=WUS2UOraGZHK0AGyroGgBg&usg=AFQjCNFMUJOEI8tFmMKWlYSKK5-oHStB9w) for writes and a [repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) for reads, depending on whether what best suits your needs.

Comment: It seems the younger you are in programming, the more attractive the "almighty object" seems :) +1 for good advice

Comment: @Patrick Indeed.  I think there's a bit of discipline that's involved, as I know I certainly was lazier when I was young and figured "who cares if it's all in one object" but then realized how it came to bite me in the ass later on.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!. Yes, I'm new in this. It's difficult to learn all the theory so fast, examples and good answers are very helpful - thank you very much.